# ​Is it possible to define parameters when a device is pushing the data to the stream and when not?

Tags: zebra-savanna

My question is basically the title - ​Is it possible to define parameters when a device is pushing the data to the stream and when not?

Comment: Can you clarify?  Are you asking if it's possible to filter what get's sent from the reader?   Or are you looking for additional uri parameters to be sent to your endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of the API it is not possible, but it would not be difficult to achieve as the main platform gateway API offered by Zebra Savanna (RFID Cloud Connect) allows to perform (read/scan) data filtering. It is something we can consider for the future roadmap provided there are good use cases supporting the need.